# Value at 'body' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to run a prediction using a sagemaker endpoint. The input format is comma separated features and | separated observations.
However when I try to iterate over the input data and invoke the end point on every iteration like this :

```
ENDPOINT_NAME = "my_endpoint"
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
results = []
for r in request_body.split('|'):
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                        ContentType='text/csv',
                                        Body=r)
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
results.append(result)
```

I get the following error:

> ValidationError: an error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'body' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

As a sanity check I ran :

```
for r in request_body.split('|'):
    print(r)
```

And I get the result I expect to get:

```
3.0,0.0,4795.0,0.0,1.0,24.0,30.0,25.0,3.0
3.0,2.0,3818.0,0.0,3.0,10.0,22.0,11.0,11.0
5.0,0.0,3565.0,0.0,1.0,79.0,89.0,80.0,-66.0
5.0,-1.0,3227.7,0.0,0.0,16.0,17.0,17.0,1.0
5.0,0.0,3375.0,0.0,2.0,21.0,45.0,22.0,6.0...etc
```

Which leads me to believe that the logic in extracting the separate observations is sound, but somehow when I execute the call I get this null value error.

The idea is to get ordered predictions so that I can later map them to an id that is not part of the training features and hence not in the dataset.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check if you are also passing to the endpoint an empty "r".
request_body.split('|') will generate a list with each of the rows of the dataframe, but it will also include one empty: ''

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in a Java application for v1 of the SDK.

In my case there was 2 reasons:

1. The format of the body was incorrect. Content Type was application/json. An array was expected and I was sending an object.
2. The second reason was that I was printing the body before sending the request. The solution for this is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html#getBody--):

> It is recommended to call ByteBuffer.duplicate() or ByteBuffer.asReadOnlyBuffer() before using or reading from the buffer.